# Log entries in google cloud logs duplicated the number of times function executed

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am triggering a google cloud function using a Cloud Pub/Sub trigger and Google Cloud Scheduler. Logs are duplicated the number of times the function has run on a given day. I am not sure if it hits a maximum of duplication's.

I have confirmed I don't have any loops causing the issue and tried outputting unstructured logs and didn't see the same duplication.

```
import logging
from google.cloud import logging as cloudlogging

# Instantiates a client
log_client = cloudlogging.Client()
log_handler = log_client.get_default_handler()
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger("cloudLogger")
cloud_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
cloud_logger.addHandler(log_handler)

cloud_logger.error('unable to delete from qb')
```

I would expect one log per log output from my script each time the script runs.

Example:

```
2020-10-01 15:25:04.562 AEST Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found
```

What I actually get is the above log multiplied by the number of times my script has run in the day with nearly identical timestamps see below after my scheduled script has run 3 times.

```
Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found 2020-10-01 15:25:04.564 AEST

Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found 2020-10-01 15:25:04.566 AEST

Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found 2020-10-01 15:25:04.567 AEST
```

I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're observing and how that is different than what you expect.  Please edit the question to more clearly explain what you've done and what your question is about that.

Comment: First run logs are added as expected.  Second run logs duplicated x2  Third run logs are duplicated x3 etc ....

Example:

2020-10-01 15:25:04.562 AEST Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found
2020-10-01 15:25:04.564 AEST Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found
2020-10-01 15:25:04.566 AEST Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found
2020-10-01 15:25:04.567 AEST Unleashed_Quickbase_Jobs-1yk5flpwmlrll found

Comment: Please **edit the question** to add new information to your question.  Don't bury information in comments, where they are easy to miss and difficult to read.  There is an edit link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: What are you expecting instead? Every time the function is executed, the function will emit the same log messages.